# Derivative of a polynomial

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

First of all, I would like to say I'm new to Mathematics StackExchange, so pardon me if there're any mistakes (until I read the right formatting rules!).

That said, we are currently learning derivatives in Cal I and I'm not sure if I'm following the right path for differentiating the following function:

$$f(x) = (8x ^ 2 + 6) ^ 6 (-9x ^ 2 - 6) ^ {14}$$

So, all I used was the Product rule combined with the power rule and got:

$$f'(x) = 6(8x^2+6)^5(-9x^2-6)^{14} + 14(8x^2+6)^6(-9x^2-6)^{13}$$

We do not have to distribute. Is that good or am I wrong?

EDIT: Thank you for your quick answers! But I forgot to mention, we have not learned the chain rule yet. Next class!

Comment: Don't forget the Chain Rule!

Comment: Try starting with a simpler problem: find the derivative of $(8x^2+6)^6$.  And read @Brian's comment too!

Comment: Suggestion: You have $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, and then find $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$ separately and then plug it into the product rule. This is so you get used to using the chain rule. As you become more used to calculus, you can get rid of this step altogether and do it all in one shot.

Comment: Forgot to mention, we have not learned the chain rule yet. Next class!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea, but you have forgotten the derivative of some parts..Namely as comments suggested the use of the chain rule.

Breaking it up into parts: let $g(x)=(8x^2+6)^6$ and $h(x)=(-9x^2-6)^{14}$.

$$f'(x)=g(x)h'(x)+h(x)g'(x)$$
$g'(x)$ and $h'(x)$ can be found using the chain rule. Since you havent learned chain rule yet, I've explained it in the context of this question. The chain rule states that you differentiate the function normally, but you have to also differentiate the inner function additionally. In these cases the inner function would be what's inside the brackets.

$$h'(x)=14(-9x^2-6)^{13}\cdot(-9x^2-6)'= 14(-9x^2-6)^{13}\cdot -18x$$
and
$$g'(x)=(8x^2+6)^6\cdot(8x^2+6)'=6(8x^2+6)^5\cdot16x$$

Comment: Thanks! We will be learning the chain rule tomorrow. I read the chapter in advance and understood thanks to your explanation :)

Comment: That's great! Glad I could help!

Comment: Sorry for the late accept btw. Midterms are here ^^

Comment: No worries, I understand. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Not quite - you forgot to apply the chain rule. For example,

$$\frac{d}{dx}(8x^2+6)^6=6(8x^2+6)^5\cdot\frac{d}{dx}(8x^2+6)=6(8x^2+6)^5(16x)=96x(8x^2+6)^5$$

I leave it to you to make the other correction.

Comment: Thank you, but I forgot to mention we haven't learned the trigonometric and chain rules yet. According to the course outline, we will see those next class.